# Передача нескольких параметров в url

Tags: python, django

Можно ли в Django каким-то образом передать несколько параметров в {% url '..' names %}. Может использовать ()? И как тогда писать в urls.py

Answer (score 1):

Укажите аргументы, разделив их пробелом:

```py
{% url 'articles' v1 v2 %}
{% url 'articles' year=v1 month=v2 %}
```

*<sup>Примечание: не смешивайте позиционный синтаксис и синтаксис ключевых слов в одном вызове</sup>*

***Пример `urls.py`:***

```py
path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.articles, name='articles')
```

P.S.: [Документация по тегу `url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: А я как-нибудь могу потом в шаблоне использовать эти параметры?

Comment: @nafagJi Плохо понимаю Ваш вопрос. Можете привести небольшой пример?

Comment: извиняюсь, имею в виду, допустим request.year мне выведет значение?